# How to check if developer pack for .Net 4.7.2 is installed?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, .net-framework-version

Is there any way to determine if the developer pack is installed or the runtime version alone is present in the server?

When I check the registry, I can see that .Net 4.7.2 is present in the system but while building the pipeline, I receive the following error. 
[image: devopserror]

Comment: Hi, how about Eriawan's answer? Does your issue could be solved with his answer?  If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Comment: @SA95 please review my answer. If it helps, mark it as answer, so you could help other SO users, like Merlin has suggested.

Comment: I have still not been able to find a way to check if the developer pack is installed. The runtime was definitely present. Did a fresh installation of the developer pack and have not encountered this issue since. Accepting Eriawan's answer as it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that your build agent does not have .NET 4.7.2 SDK and Targeting Pack.

Since the .NET Framework 4.7, Microsoft has combined the SDK and targeting pack into one "Developer Pack".

The official landing page to get these Developer Pack (including previous version of .NET Framework before 4.7), is this: 
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks

Before installing these Developer Pack, you ***must ensure that the machine that host your build agents must have the .NET Framework related runtime installed***. For example, the .NET 4.7.2 Developer Pack requires .NET Framework 4.7.2 runtime installed before.

On some later Windows releases, you have to pay attention that minimum .NET Framework runtime version will always be in sync with the Windows used. This fact may save you some time for checking the available .NET Framework runtime installed.

For example, Windows Server 2019 has already .NET Framework 4.7.2 runtime installed. 
This is the official complete list of available versions of .NET Framework, please visit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: > "you must ensure that the machine that host your build agents must have the .NET Framework related runtime installed"

I just upgraded a Windows Server 2019 machine from .NET Framework runtime 4.7.2 and .NET Framework Dev Pack 4.6.1 to Dev Pack 4.8 and it updated the runtime as well just fine.

Comment: For CI machine, the .NET Framework Dev Pack _may_ require us to ensure the .NET Framework ref assemblies to be installed as "runtime". Windows Server 2019 by default has .NET Framework 4.8 runtime available, but this alone won't guarantee your compilation when using specific TFM will not fail. You still need the reference assemblies.